# Question about how data sent from the tmp102 is processed

Tags: sensor, i2c, digital-communications

I wired up a [TMP102 sensor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11931)(on a breakout board) from sparkfun. The wiring made sense, standard i2c wiring. Here is the [TMP102's datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temperature/tmp102.pdf). I used [this guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/photon-remote-temperature-sensor#program-it) as a guide for the program that I wrote. The program that is running on the particle photon(the microcontroller board that I am using), has a confusing line of code. The line of code that I am referring to does this: The bits of the MSB that are received by the microcontroller(Most significant byte, not bit) are shifted left, 8 times and then Or'ed with the LSB(least significant byte). The bits of the result are then shifted right 4 times. Lastly, the whole thing is multiplied by 0.0625. This line of code sums up what I just said, and can be seen in the guide linked above:

**int temp = ((( MSB << 8) | LSB) >> 4) * 0.0625;**

I got everything to work(it measures temperature), but I don't know ***why*** it works. My question is: why is the above line of code required? Why do these operations need to be completed?. And as a side question, if the bits in a byte are shifted left 8 times, wouldn't that result in a value of 0000 0000? If my question is a bit vague, please tell me.

Comment: An int value is 16 bits, so shifting the received byte left by 8 bits puts that byte in the upper half of the 16 bit int temp.

Comment: To be clear on the size of variables, the preferred definition of temp would be uint16_t temp, clearly declaring it as a 16 bit value.

Comment: So a uint8_t is an integer consisting of 8 bits? I've seen uint_16's in code before and just ignored the number 16. I thought that they were just another way of saying "int x". Thanks for the info. Seems like a basic concept which only a noob like me would overlook...

Comment: Just to clarify (or confuse?), in C, an int must be at least 16 bits, but may be larger if the processor can "naturally" handle larger values, and a long int must be at least 32 bits (If I remember correctly).  The uint16_t type notation was introduced to clarify exactly what size variable is required.

Comment: So a uint32_t x = ... is the same as : long x=...? Are these two statements completely equivalent in terms of their behavior and characteristics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ( MSB << 8) | LSB) is understood: you want to concatinate the two bytes together. Apparently, in LSB only the [7:4] are valid data. So, you >>4 to get rid of the [3:0] bits. Now, the 0.0625 multiplication is not clear, but it is the same thing as dividing by 16, or performing another >>4 bit shift. The end result in the *temp* is the MSB only.

```
MSB: 1010 1010
LSB: 0001 XXXX

MSB<<8     1010 1010 0000 0000  
LSB                  0001 XXXX

when ORed
           1010 1010 0001 XXXX

when shifted >>4
           0000 1010 1010 0001

when multiplied *0.0625
           0000 0000 1010 1010=MSB
```

Comment: I thought concatenation was when you "combine two bits": for example if 0101 was concatenated with 1101 then the result is 01011101?

Comment: So lets say the MSB is 1101 0010 and the LSB is 0110 1011. According to the line of code, the bits in 1101 0010 are shifted left 8 times, so the reult is 0000 0000. This is then OR'ed with the LSB, resulting in a value of (0110 1011). So doesn't this:  MSB << 8) | LSB, just give you the LSB?

Comment: Oh, I see the part about concatenation. If the bits in the MSB are shifted left 8 times, the right most 8 bits are all 0's but the left 8 bits are the original MSB.

Comment: Just found some info. On the sparkfun product page it says: "The TMP102 is a digital sensor (I2C a.k.a. TWI), has a resolution of 0.0625°C" Maybe this has something to do with the multiplication of the resulted byte, by 0.0625?

Comment: What do you mean by the [7:4]?

Comment: You device provides 12bit data. From what I understood the 11:4 goes to your MSB and the 3:0 goes to the LSB[7:4], the LSB[3:0] do not matter, so you shift >>4 to get rid of them.

Comment: I still don't understand the usage of the colon in between numbers, sorry I'm a noob. Does [7:4] mean bits seven to four, inclusive of both?And in this notation, are the bits zero indexed(right most bit is referred to as the 0'th place)?

Comment: correct [7:0] is eight bits. this is a common notation.

Comment: I think that I am overlooking something, but if your explanation is correct, after the line of code executes, the result is equal to the MSB? If that is true, what is the point of the line of code?, why not just use the MSB that is received?

Comment: Naz, I understand your explanation. But I still don't see why the sensor sends data using two bytes, only to result(after the line of code that I am referring to in my question is executed) in a byte which has exact value of one of the bytes sent before the line of code. I will play around with the code and try to shed more light on the matter. Anyways, thanks. You helped me understand it and cleared up my flawed question about bit shifting.

Comment: Hmm.  I added another line of code after the line that my question is about. It is: temp = (MSB)*1.8 + 32; When printed it shows a value of 73(F), while the regular one: int temp = ((( MSB << 8) | LSB) >> 4) * 0.0625; shows a value of 75. Over time after about a minute, the value printed by the (MSB)*1.8 + 32, increases until it equals the value of the regular line of code.

Comment: It seems as if int temp = ((( MSB << 8) | LSB) >> 4) * 0.0625 is more "sensitive" than int temp=(MSB)*1.8 + 32.